# How to convert scriptPubKey bytes to Bitcoin address

Tags: python, bitcoin

I am currently trying myself in parsing the blockchain using [pyblockchain](https://github.com/toidi/pyblockchain). My problem is that I am not able to encode the `scriptPubKey` correctly - although I don't know what I could possibly do wrong.

Below you can see how I traverse the blockchain:

```
from blockchain.reader import BlockchainFileReader

import hashlib
import base58

block_reader = BlockchainFileReader('/media/Data/btc/blocks/blk00325.dat')

count = 0

for block in block_reader:    
    count +=1        
    for t in block.transactions:
        for outp in t.outputs:
            addr = base58.b58encode(outp.script_pub_key)
            if addr.startswith('1'):
                print(addr)        
    if count >= 5:
        break
```

If I, in my Jupyter notebook, take a look at `outp`, I'll find for

```
outp.script_pub_key
>> b'v\xa9\x14\x1e\xbev\x83\xceJd\xad\xc9\x17\xe9\xb1\x93\x7f\x12&Q\xcb\xab\xa1\x88\xac'
```

this:

```
base58.b58encode(outp.script_pub_key)
>> 'pkJBVCg6k54E7ZiP7cvxbCvtN9aY9zEcgK'
```

and this is not a [valid bitcoin address](http://lenschulwitz.com/base58).

Apparently, bitcoin addresses are supposed to be encoded i [Base58Check](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding) - however, that does not work either:

```
base58.b58encode_check(outp.script_pub_key)
>> '6PSJQapdQn8VeG9SBuZdH8q2ysyP4ND6dmspzLZb'
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score -2):

For C++ there is
`bool ExtractDestination(const CScript& scriptPubKey, CTxDestination& addressRet)`
directly in the code here
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0cda5573405d75d695aba417e8f22f1301ded001/src/script/standard.cpp#L156

And thus, the solution looks pretty simple

```
const CScript & scriptPublicKey = block.vtx[ i ]->vout[ j ].scriptPubKey ;
CTxDestination destination ;
std::string address = "unknown" ;
if ( ExtractDestination( scriptPublicKey, destination ) )
    address = CBitcoinAddress( destination ).ToString() ;
```

As for Python.. The problem is to convert `ExtractDestination` logic to Python's language at first, I bet